# how to create service groups in wso2 DSS server

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I need to create a several services . I found we can create one query service easily.
how to create service groups in WSO2  DSS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to use use below example.

[Example](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Service+Group+Dashboard)

Comment: please provide me a another example